# positive Error correction term, what could be wrong

Tags: cointegration, ecm

here is the basic regression: 
log(Robots per capita)~share of midage+share of older+log(gdp)
I obtain good results but all my variables are unit root.
So I tried correcting this doing the following.
(my model residuals are stationary)

```
model1 <- lm(log(normRobots)~smidage+solder+log(gdp)))
error.ecm1 <- model1$residuals[-1:-2]

log.normRobots.d <- diff(log(normRobots))[-1]
smidage.d <- diff(smidage)[-1]
solder.d <- diff(solder)[-1]
log.normRobots.d1 <- diff(log(normRobots))[-(length(log(normRobots)) - 1)]
smidage.d1 <- diff(smidage[-(length(smidage) - 1)])
solder.d1 <- diff(solder[-(length(solder)-1)])
log.gdp.d <- diff(log(gdp))[-1]
log.gdp.d1 <- diff(log(gdp)[-(length(log(gdp))-1)])

ecm.normRobots <- lm(log.normRobots.d ~ error.ecm1 + log.normRobots.d1 + smidage.d1 + solder.d1 + log.gdp.d1)
summary(ecm.normRobots)

Call:
lm(formula = log.normRobots.d ~ error.ecm1 + log.normRobots.d1 + 
    smidage.d1 + solder.d1 + log.gdp.d1)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.246532 -0.130685  0.003535  0.083758  0.279330 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         0.07296    0.11624   0.628  0.53812    
error.ecm1          0.99675    0.19136   5.209 5.92e-05 ***
log.normRobots.d1  -0.32230    0.14772  -2.182  0.04262 *  
smidage.d1        -50.11177   22.51936  -2.225  0.03909 *  
solder.d1          15.35789   60.01855   0.256  0.80094    
log.gdp.d1         -8.04693    2.68892  -2.993  0.00781 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1706 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.69, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6039 
F-statistic: 8.014 on 5 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.0003991
```

I obtain a positive ECT. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Please provide the code used to generate 'model1'.

Comment: I think I have answered a few similar questions, see [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22error+correction%22+positive+is%3Aanswer+user%3A53690).

Comment: Here, I've added the code line for model1. I just went through my data again and realize that smidage is second order integrated. Could this be the reason ? if so what should I adjust ?